# sql syntax error when I am copying data in one table

Tags: mysql

I am getting an SQL syntax error in my query.
where am I wrong ?

```
update ko
set ko.morasaradnik = k1.morasaradnik
from f_kontniokvir ko inner join f_kontniokvir k1 on
ko.sifra = k1.sifra and ko.fiskalnagodina = 23 and k1.fiskalnagodina = 24
```

Comment: Please post the exact error. We cannot solve problem by guessing.

Answer (score 3):

You are using SQL Server syntax for update with a join.  The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
update f_kontniokvir ko inner join
       f_kontniokvir k1
       on ko.sifra = k1.sifra and ko.fiskalnagodina = 23 and k1.fiskalnagodina = 24
  set ko.morasaradnik = k1.morasaradnik;
```